# UK Naturalisation while claiming benefits

Tags: united-kingdom, naturalization, immigration

I am an EU national and started thinking about naturalization. I heard that one of the criteria is that you must not have claimed benefits for more than 3 months in the last year. If I have, does it mean I'm not eligible?

I meet all other criteria alright. But I've been on benefits. Is that a deal-breaker?

Comment: Where have you heard that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I heard that one of the criteria is that you must not have claimed benefits for more than 3 months in the last year.**

I don't know where you heard this, but it is not one of the eligibility requirements for EU citizens.  See pages 14 to 18 of the government's published guidance in the [Naturalisation Booklet](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/form-an-guidance).

Comment: Watched a youtube video once, hardly a source. I'll read that document. Thank you for the answer.